# Protractor can't find button with $ctrl on ng-click

Tags: css, angularjs, selenium, xpath, protractor

I cannot find buttons that have this $ctrl part with protractor.
Example of a button:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary ng-scope" ng-click="$ctrl.openProfileModal()" ng-if="$ctrl.admin &amp;&amp; $ctrl.networkInfo.scenario !== 'simple_mesh'" 
ng-disabled="$ctrl.stats['5G'].full &amp;&amp; $ctrl.stats['2G'].full"><i class=""></i>Add virtual AP</button>
```

The reasonable solution seems to be to search with ng-click:

```
addVAPButton = element(by.css('[ng-click="$ctrl.openProfileModal()"]'))
```

But it does not work. I've tried it with various comma combinations, searching by class, by ng-if, by xpath, tried adding id, name, other attributes to this button, but nothing helped Selenium find it. I can find other elements from the page that do not have $ctrl by ng-click, name, id, model, so I suspect that there is something about $ctrl that is not compatible with protractor. Any solutions or workarounds to reach this button?

Protractor version:5.3.0
Angular version: 1.5.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the button with text as **Add virtual AP** you can use the following line of code :

```
addVAPButton = element(by.css("button.btn.btn-primary.ng-scope > i"))
```

**Note** : As the *button* is an *Angular Element* you have to wait for the *button* to be *clickable*

---

### Update

As an alternative you can try either of the following options :

```
addVAPButton = element(by.css("button.btn.btn-primary.ng-scope"))
```

Or

```
addVAPButton = element(by.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-primary ng-scope' and contains(.,'Add virtual AP')]"))
```

Comment: Still does not work (I tried with different combinations of browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false) and browser.sleep(), still can't find the button)
Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, button.btn.btn-primary.ng-scope > i)

Comment: Apparently both css and xpath selectors work if I add this instead of a simple click:
browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(addVAPButton), 10000).then(function(){
addVAPButton.click();})

Comment: Thats exactly what I mentioned in my answer as a footnote as in `As the button is an Angular Element you have to wait for the button to be clickable`. As I work with pure _WebDriver_ variants I am not accustomed with the **protractor** related `waiter` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way that works with any selector (css, ng-click, id, name, xpath, whatever):

```
addVAPButton = $("[ng-click=\"$ctrl.openProfileModal()\"]");
browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(addVAPButton), 10000).then(function(){
addVAPButton.click();})
```